# rich or poor vs. whether you are rich or poor

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunction-reduction

Are the following sentences interchangeable?

> a. Whether you are rich or poor, I still love you.

> b. Rich or poor, I still love you.

Answer (score 1):

From context, the person saying (b) is likely trying to convey the meaning expressed by (a).  The phrase *Rich or poor* in (b), however, has no clear referent.

(a) is clear and hence better.

Edit after comments from @FumbleFingers

The default referent / subject after a "fronted" non-specific adverbial element is in fact the first credible noun that follows. So by default that's I (the speaker) here.  That would mean

> Whether I'm rich or poor, I still love you.

Hence sentence (b) strictly has a different meaning from (a) and is at best unclear even if interpreted from context.

Comment: The *default* referent / subject after a "fronted" non-specific adverbial element is in fact *the first credible noun* that follows. So by default that's ***I*** (the speaker) here - *Whether **I'm** rich or poor, I still love you*. If course, sometimes the semantics of the utterance make that unlikely or impossible, as when the "seeker" playing "hide and seek" says ***Ready or not**, I'm coming looking for you!* (where it wouldn't really make sense if we understood that as *Regardless of whether **I'm** ready or not...*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Yes, I agree with you and have incorporated your comments in my updated answer; I hope you would not mind.

Comment: I can't really endorse your judgement: *(a) is clear **and hence better*** - but that was there when I first upvoted your answer, anyway. When I said the "default" interpretation was ***I*** (the speaker) in OP's example, I meant ***syntactically***. But in practice, ***semantics*** (focusing on ***likely meaning in context***) strongly steers us towards a different interpretation (even more so with my ***ready or not*** example). So in the real world, there's little or no ambiguity - and people generally prefer ***shorter*** utterances *if the intended meaning is reasonably clear*.